# Define dynamic component in Vue & Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have a simple dynamic component which is missing type checking.
How can I do proper type checking instead of using 'any', which is the only thing that worked.

```
<script>
...

interface {
  [key: string]: any
}

const pages: page = {
  Intro,
  Play,
  End,
}
</script>

<template>
  <component :is="pages[state.page]" />
</template>
```

Comment: I take it this is vue3 ... have you checked https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/options-api.html#typing-component-props or https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html as appropriate?

Comment: You may not need a type at all. WIthout `page` type, it's inferred as `[string]: Component`. For specific keys, use `{...} as const`

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes it is Vue3. But I can't find any reference to the declaring for dynamic components in the links you've shared.

Comment: @EstusFlask I thought it'll be inferred too but my pages[state.page] is flagging as an issue without the type declaration.

Answer (score 2):

### **Vue3: Use Vue's `Component` type:**

Make use of Vue's `Component` type, but also make sure your interface is actually used. In addition, the MyComponentList references should point to a registered (ie imported) component.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    import type { Component } from 'vue'
    import MyComponentA from "@/components/MyComponentA.vue"
    import MyComponentB from "@/components/MyComponentB.vue"
    import MyComponentC from "@/components/MyComponentC.vue"
    
    interface IComponents {
        [key: string]: Component
    }
    
    // Make a list of component items
    const MyComponentList: IComponents = {
    
       // Keys could possibly be without quotes, but this is more explicit and less confusing.
      "MyComponentA": MyComponentA,
      "MyComponentB": MyComponentB,
      "MyComponentC": MyComponentC
    }
</script>
```

Then in your template, you pass a dynamic component name (`SomeString`) that should match any key in `MyComponentList`, e.g. "MyComponentA":

```
<component :is="MyComponentList[SomeString as keyof typeof MyComponentList]" />
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for Vue3, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

expect string or Component so, in your case you should import Component from Vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
 import { type Component } from 'vue';
 interface {
   [key: string]: Component
 }

 const pages: page = {
 Intro,
 Play,
 End,
}
<script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
interface page {
  Intro: VueComponent;
  Play: VueComponent;
  End: VueComponent;
}
```

Comment: Error shows as "Cannot find name 'VueComponent'.

Comment: Did you import it from Vue, to make it easier hover over a component and you would see the class or interface it's implementing.